# A word to call an analysis or an opinion "appreciative of the topic's subtleties"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In my mother tongue (Czech), I'd use a word that would directly translate to English as "sensitive" (*citlivý*), but that doesn't quite carry the same meaning.

I'm looking for a word that encapsulates that the person doing the analysis is *not* quick to draw conclusions, and instead carefully takes heed of the topic's subtleties and intricacies. Something in between "insightful" and "incisive" and "humble"...

edit: Sample sentence would be: "In spite of my expectations, the newspaper article about immigration was surprisingly [sensitive]."

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the requirement, but I'm not sure I've done much to clarify the meaning...

Comment: Just to nail it down a little more, should the adjective apply _only_ to the paper being written, or also to the person writing it?..." a word that encapsulates that the person doing the analysis is not quick to draw conclusions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> carefully takes heed of the topic's subtleties and intricacies.

Perhaps ***perceptive*** would fit your purpose:

> **perceptive**
>   2.
>   a. Having the ability to perceive; keen in discernment.
>   b. Marked by discernment and understanding; sensitive.
>   *-- [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/perceptive)*

Note also the synonym ***discerning***.

Comment: perceptive and discerning feel closest of these answers what I mean, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like [discerning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discerning) here.  It has some of the same meaning as wise from experience, and the ability to see through clutter or unimportant details.

discerning adjective
dis·​cern·​ing | \ di-ˈsər-niŋ  \
Definition of discerning
: showing insight and understanding : DISCRIMINATING
a discerning critic

Answer (score 0):

> If you **deliberate**, you think about something carefully, especially
>   before making a very important decision.

As in:

He/She **deliberated** the topic carefully, heeding its subtleties and intricacies.